# how to get the latest changes from others and do not use my changes in my local branch?

Tags: git, branch, fetch

I have some updates in my local branch, which is called `topic` branch, on this branch, I updated a file `a.txt`, but I did not stage and commit it, then I did `git fetch`, there are some new commits made by others show up in the version tree, lets say it is `veresion3` and `version4` are new fetched commits, and there are changes in the file `a.txt`, then I want to use all the changes in the `versi
on4`, and throw my changes in file `a.txt`, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw away your changes in `a.txt`:

```
git checkout a.txt
```

Get new commits in your branch:

```
git merge origin/master
```

(assuming the changes made by others are on master)

Comment: while, I just want to use the changes in file a.txt, so I can do some updates based on it, I do not want to merge my changes to the master

Comment: @user2131316 you said you want to throw away your changes in `a.txt`, no?

Comment: yes, I want to throw away my changes in a.txt, but I want to use the updates fetched from the new commits, before that I do not want to push anything to the master

Answer (score 0):

In order to copy the current state of `a.txt` from `version4`, you can use the following command:

```
$ git checkout origin/master a.txt
```

This assumes that origin/master points to `version4`.

This will do two things:

1. replace the unstaged/uncommitted contents of your `a.txt` file in your workspace
2. will NOT create a merge, or integrate anything else in `version4`, just copies the snapshot of `a.txt`

NOTE: You will still have to commit the `a.txt` file locally after having done this command.
NOTE: You can replace `a.txt` with a directory path to get copy all files under a directory to your local workspace.